# Running JBoss Server from eclipse [Adempiere project]

Tags: eclipse, jboss, erp, adempiere

For testing the webui of adempiere, I need to build the code and deploy it every time with all change. Its much time consuming. The [remote debugging](http://tekadempiere.blogspot.in/2013/12/to-debug-adempiere-web.html) is quite useful. But the build, setup and server running time remains the same.
Can we run the JBoss server through eclipse ? Hence can we write the code and test it on debug mode?

Answer (score 4):

You Can run the jboss server in eclipse and deploy adempiere projects in jboss also

1. Download the [jboss4.2.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss/JBoss-4.2.3.GA) and place into your desire location in your drive.
2. Extract the jboss zip file (let say /home/Giri/Server/jboss4.2.3GA/....)
3. Open your eclipse IDE, and open the server pane

   - Click on the Window  And choose Show View
   - It will open a popup and select the server (By writing the help text you will get)
4. Right click on the server editor, `New`---->`Server`

   - It will open the a new server pop-up
   - Select the jboss and select the jboss version as the 4.2
5. Click on the Next button
6. Here you need to select the your jboss server path (as previously i mentioned /home/Giri/Server/jboss4.2.3GA/ )
7. Click on the `Next` (no need to change the ports)---> `Finish`

   - Don't bother about the project `Add And Remove Project`
8. Now in server editor you will get a jboss server details in single line
9. Now double click on the server, or Right click on the jboss server And select the `Open`
10. It will open server details page
11. Now update the following settings

    - In `Publishing` :- Select `Never select auotmatically`
    - In `Time Out`  :- Set `start time` as `5000`
    - Save(CTRL+S) the settings and close the settings
12. Click on the `Open launch configuration`
13. It will open the a pop-up
14. Now Navigate into `classpath` tab, And select the `User Entries` and add the following mentioned jars by clicking on the `Add Jars` button at right side

    - trunk\tools\lib*.jars (Except cglib.jar, log4j.jar, jnlp.jar, javaee.jar)
    - trunk\japserreportstool\lib*.jars (Except jfreechart***.jar)
    - and add the javaw.jar from the jre library (by using `Add external jars`)
15. If you want to configure the properties files then add the properties files details into `Arguments` tab
16. Save it and close it
17. Right click on the server and Click on the `Add And Remove` Select available installers and add to right side tab, and click on Finish.
18. Run click on jboss and publish after that start it....

Hope your server will start properly .....

Comment: When I tried these steps (for running JBoss through the eclipse) , getting  a deploy error ::  Deployment FAILED reason: Error during deploy; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JACC:Error PolicyConfigurationFactory : cannot find class : null)

Comment: @Mubli:- Need some more log notes for investigation. And make sure that you have done 14th step correctly.